# SQL syntax error with working SQL statement

Tags: java, mysql, database

My problem is this piece of code:

```java
 public void addSensorData(String strJSON)
            throws SQLException, JsonProcessingException, ParseException {
        JsonNode data = new ObjectMapper().readTree(strJSON);

        //getting key from json node and convert to TimeStamp
        Timestamp ts = new java.sql.Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                .parse(data.fieldNames().next()).getTime());
        String keyString = ts.toString().split("\\.")[0];

        if (!getSensorData(keyString).next()) {

            String sql = "INSERT INTO `sensor_data` VALUES(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            PreparedStatement prep = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            prep.setInt(1, data.path(keyString).path("temperature").asInt());
            prep.setInt(2, data.path(keyString).path("humidity").asInt());
            prep.setInt(3, data.path(keyString).path("soil_moisture").asInt());
            prep.setInt(4, data.path(keyString).path("brightness").asInt());
            prep.setInt(5, data.path(keyString).path("water_flow").asInt());
            prep.setTimestamp(6, ts);

            System.out.println(prep);

            prep.execute(sql);
            prep.close();
        } else {
            // TODO: 05/04/2022 maybe ne error message
        }
    }
```

Input is:

```java
addSensorData("{\"2022-03-28 22:07:12\": {\"humidity\": 35,\"soil_moisture\": 70," +
                "\"temperature\": 31,\"brightness\": 500,\"water_flow\": 1000}}");
```

All of this seems to work just fine, until I want to execute the statement.
The error message is this:

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement: INSERT INTO `sensor_data` VALUES(31,35,70,500,1000,'2022-03-28 22:07:12')
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?)' at line 1
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:120)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeInternal(StatementImpl.java:763)
    at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:648)
    at hbs.nb.marsgarten.database.Querying.addSensorData(Querying.java:109)
    at hbs.nb.marsgarten.database.test.main(test.java:15)
```

I'm confused because when I paste the statement showing in the error message it just works.

This is what I'm creating the table with:

```java
public void createTableSensorData()
            throws SQLException {
        String sql = "CREATE TABLE `sensor_data`" +
                "(temperature INTEGER not NULL," +
                "humidity INTEGER not NULL," +
                "soil_moisture INTEGER not NULL," +
                "brightness INTEGER not NULL," +
                "water_flow INTEGER not NULL," +
                "timestamp TIMESTAMP not NULL," +
                "PRIMARY KEY (timestamp))";
        conn.createStatement().executeUpdate(sql);
    }
```

Comment: It should be `prep.execute();` - not `prep.execute(sql);` which is from Statement and cannot deal with `?`.

Comment: Thank you. You really helped me out. That fixed everything